# Assembly PUSH instruction with an OFFSET tag

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, ghidra

I've written a simple 'Hello World' program in assembly:

```
global  _main
extern  _printf

section .text
_main:
    push  offset  message
    call  _printf
    add   esp, 4
    ret
section .data
    message db  'Hello, World2', 10, 0
```

I've opened the compiled .EXE in *Ghidra* tool (freeware *IDA* alternative) and when I look at the generated assembly code listing,  there is something like this:

```
 push  message
 call  _printf
 add   esp,0x4
```

My question is: why is there no `offset` keyword there (like in the source)? Is it optional or so? Moreover when I'd like to patch the instruction, the tool doesn't allow me to type the `offset` keyword...

Comment: The syntax depends on the tool. Some assemblers use `offset`, some don't. Those that don't, usually require `[]` brackets for memory references to differentiate it from an address.

Comment: What assembler did you use in the first place to build your program?  That looks like NASM syntax, except that there's an `offset` in there which isn't valid for NASM.

Comment: How does Ghidra disassemble an instruction like `push [disp32]` instead of `push imm32`?  e.g. NASM `push dword [message]` vs. NASM `push message`.  Every assembly syntax needs *some* way to differentiate those two forms.

Answer (score 2):

Assemblers belong to one of two believes.

Assemblers that require square brackets to read/write memory will not need the `offset` tag to reference the offset of the label. This is the **N**ASM style.
These assemblers can allow or prohibit the use of `offset`.

Assemblers that don't require square brackets to read/write memory will need the `offset` tag to reference the offset of the label. This is the **M**ASM style.

Comment: Ok Guys, but the _Ghidra_ doesn't allow either the `offset` syntax nor `[]`. Here is what I can insert as an operand for the PUSH instruction when patching:[link](https://imgur.com/a/DZJCygi)

Comment: It does work for me. However it's not obvious how it shows you can't use `[]`. Anyway, if you want an address you do not need the `[]` nor the `offset`.

Comment: OK, so that means that the assembler buid-in the tool  doesn't require offset and [] syntax?

Comment: It would require `[]` for memory references or maybe something like `push word ptr [si]`. It certainly needs a way to differentiate pushing an address vs a value.

Comment: You might also just assemble `push [si]` or similar and see how ghidra disassembles that.